# I need to generate a large technical document with dynamically generated data from java

Tags: java

I'm writing an Interface Control Document (ICD) that contains **dynamic** data queried from relation databases and extracted from Magic Draw SysML/UML models. The java "backend" to obtain/generate this information already exists. All the data I need to generate the document is stored in java objects/collections.

Currently, the ICD is generated with Velocity scripts in a Microsoft word document...which is difficult to work with. I would like to be able to generate the document with Latex from a more programming friendly context.  Is there a library or .jar file to import which enables programmers to make Latex calls to create paragraphs, sections, tables, etc. with dynamic data from a java context?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I would guess the usual way is to handle the whole document as writing text from Java producing a latex document that you process to get the final pdf rather than processing individual paragraphs as separate latex calls. But perhaps that doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: No idea of Java, but for dynamic LaTeX reports `knitr` could be a goos solution if your databases can be exported to some manageable for R language  (CSV, Excel, SPSS, ODBC...) and you have some experience with R or python. If this is not a potion for you check if `datatool` LaTeX package is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Fran, I like your suggestion but the “long pole in the tent” is extracting the data from the sysml and uml models from magic draw. That’s in Java - not much I can do - although I could save as csv or something…. David, that’s where I run into a problem. It’s a technical document with sections numbers like 3.4.2.7.1. Trying to handle the whole thing at once (instead of in sections) is the challenge. I guess I could create some sort of object oriented structures in Java representing the latex components/sections (chapter, table, figure,etc), then after processing the dyn

Comment: Maybe a templating engine like the [Java LaTeX Report (JLR)](https://www.nixo-soft.de/jlrtutorial/) library (which is based on the  Velocity Template Language (VTL) from Apache) could be useful here.